# adb: failed to stat app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk: No such file or directory

Tags: android, react-native, adb, deviceid

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.57.3

Getting an error when connecting Android device via USB on a new app:

```
> adb devices
```

List of devices attached
988se6666555453 device

```
> react-native run-android --deviceId 988se6666555453
```

Answer (score 1):

From the root of your directory App run:

```
> adb devices
```

*List of devices attached*
**988se6666555453** device

copy your **deviceId** if your device is connected and run

```
> adb -s 988se6666555453 install android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk

> react-native run-android --deviceId 988se6666555453
```